# JS .focus() working in snippet but not in document

Tags: javascript

I just started working with JS again (it's been awhile) so I'm a bit rusty! I'm trying to make an input come into focus when a button is pressed. Can anyone explain why this works in the snippet but not in my document?

```js
document.getElementById('Search_Button').addEventListener('click', function () 
{
    document.getElementById('Search_Input').focus();
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Search_Button" />

<label for="Search_Button"><div id="Search_Bar_Dismiss_Box"></div></label>

<div id="Search_Box">
    <input type="search" name="Search" id="Search_Input" placeholder="Search" />
    <label for="Search_Button"><img src="SVG/Back_Arrow.svg" id="Cancel_Search"></label>
</div>
```

Here is my entire document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

      document.getElementById('Search_Button').addEventListener('click', function()
      {
          document.getElementById('Search_Input').focus();
      });

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="checkbox" id="Search_Button" /> <!-- Opens Search Bar -->

   <label for="Search_Button"><div id="Search_Bar_Dismiss_Box"></div></label>

    <div id="Search_Box">
        <input type="search" name="Search" id="Search_Input" placeholder="Search" />
        <label for="Search_Button"><img src="SVG/Back_Arrow.svg" id="Cancel_Search"></label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reason is your script execute first but document loaded late. to correct this ad your script in footer section. When script execute it can access id content.

Comment: @SunnyS.M oh wow I completely forgot about putting JS at the bottom! Thanks!

Comment: i also answered.. Please vote to my answer as solved answer

Comment: Many Thanks... to vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Code: Add script in footer section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="Search_Button" /> <!-- Opens Search Bar -->

<!--              SEARCH BAR           -->

    <label for="Search_Button">
        <div id="Search_Bar_Dismiss_Box">
        </div> <!-- Search Bar Dismiss Box -->
    </label> <!-- Dismisses the search bar -->

    <div id="Search_Box">

        <input type="search" name="Search" id="Search_Input" placeholder="Search" />
        <label for="Search_Button">
            <img src="SVG/Back_Arrow.svg" id="Cancel_Search">
        </label>

    </div> <!-- Search Box -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('Search_Button').addEventListener('click', function (){
        document.getElementById('Search_Input').focus();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code on *window.onload* function

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    document.getElementById('Search_Button').addEventListener('click', function ()            
    {
        document.getElementById('Search_Input').focus();
    });
};
```

hope it helps